# I need to dynamically assign radio button in a php file quiz

Tags: php, html, mysql, radio-button

I'm designing a dynamically generated quiz page (using mysqli / php / html) and I need to insert some radio buttons in order to validate the answers.
The problem that I have is that when printing the radio buttons inside the loop, they do not uncheck properly - instead of having 4 sets of radio buttons / question, my radio buttons are assigned like this: question 1 a) with question 2 a) and so on.
Does anybody have any idea on how to remedy this?

```
$sql = "SELECT id, descr, a,b,c,d FROM question ORDER BY rand() LIMIT  15";
$result = $conn->query($sql);



if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        print "<strong>".$row["descr"] ."</strong><br>";
        echo "<br>";
        echo 'a:'.$row["a"].'<td><cb><input type="radio" name="a" value="$row["a"]"></cb></td>'."<br>";
        echo "<br>";
        echo 'b:'. $row["b"].'<td><cb><input type="radio" name="b" value="$row["b"]"></cb></td>'."<br>";
        echo "<br>";
        echo 'c:'.$row["c"].'<td><cb><input type="radio" name="c" value="$row["c"]"></cb></td>'."<br>";
        echo "<br>";
        echo 'd:'. $row["d"].'<td><cb><input type="radio" name="d" value="$row["d"]"></cb></td>'."<br>";
        echo "<br>";

    }

} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```

Comment: If radio buttons share the same name, you can only select one. In your case you have same radio button names for all questions

Answer (score 0):

You will need to include something unique to each question in the radio button name attribute, such as:

```
<input type="radio" name="a<?= $row['question_number'] ?" />
```

`question_number` is just some made up field but this should be something that is unique to each question. This would result in something like:

```
Question 1:    
<input type="radio" name="a1" />
<input type="radio" name="b1" />
<input type="radio" name="c1" />
<input type="radio" name="d1" />

Question 2:
<input type="radio" name="a2" />
<input type="radio" name="b3" />
<input type="radio" name="c4" />
<input type="radio" name="d5" />
```

Comment: Problem solved but now the questions and answers don't appear.   echo "<strong>".$nr .$row["descr"] ."</strong><br>";
  echo "<br>";
  echo 'a:'.$row["a"].'<td><cb><input type="radio" name="'.$row["a"].$nr.'" value="a"></cb></td>'."<br>";
  echo "<br>";

Comment: My apologies - the code in my answer is an excerpt containing an example of how do modify your existing code, as opposed to a replacement for your code. The part to look for is the `name=` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following :

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        print "<strong>".$row["descr"] ."</strong><br>";
        echo "<br>";
        echo 'a:'.$row["a"].'<td><cb><input type="radio" name="q'.$row["id"].'" value="a"></cb></td>'."<br>";
        echo "<br>";
        echo 'b:'. $row["b"].'<td><cb><input type="radio" name="q'.$row["id"].'" value="b"></cb></td>'."<br>";
        echo "<br>";
        echo 'c:'.$row["c"].'<td><cb><input type="radio" name="q'.$row["id"].'" value="c"></cb></td>'."<br>";
        echo "<br>";
        echo 'd:'. $row["d"].'<td><cb><input type="radio" name="q'.$row["id"].'" value="d"></cb></td>'."<br>";
        echo "<br>";

    }

} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

This way each question creates a group of radio buttons having the same name and differing in their value, therefore when you submit you can check e.g.: `$_GET["qXXX"]` to determine what the answer was for question XXX (e.g. a, b, c, or d )